Test suite failed to run : Invariant violation: "Buffer.from("") instanceof Uint8Array" is incorrectly false
**Invariant violation: "Buffer.from("") instanceof Uint8Array" is incorrectly false
This indicates that your JavaScript environment is broken. You cannot use                                                               
esbuild in this environment because esbuild relies on this invariant. This                                                              
is not a problem with esbuild. You need to fix your environment instead.                                                                
                                                                                                                                        
  1 | import 'zone.js';                                                                                                                 
  2 | import 'zone.js/testing';                                                                                                         
> 3 | import 'jest-preset-angular';                                                                                                     
    | ^                                                                                                                                 
  4 |
  5 | import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
  6 | import {

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:201:9)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/test.ts:3:1)
  at fulfilled (node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:178:32)**

I tried fixing the jest env.

I managed to fix this with removing old import and add a new one as below:
// import 'jest-preset-angular'; // remove this import
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest'; // add this one

Also this might also be relevant to configure transformignorePatters properly in jest.config.ts.
I hope this helps.
